Maximise Photoshop window fails
In my script I have:
def maximize_photoshop_window():
    photoshop_window = pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle("Adobe Photoshop")[0]
    photoshop_window.maximize()
    time.sleep(1)  # Give a little time for the window to maximize

    def activate_photoshop_window():
    # Activate the Photoshop window titled "Untitled-1"
    pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle("Untitled-1")[0].activate()
    time.sleep(1)  # Give a little time for the window to activate` 

# It stops with an error at this point (in Pycharm)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    maximize_photoshop_window()

The error is:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\1_python\Photoshop draw
circle in untitled-1 with spacebar.py", line 54, in <module>
    maximize_photoshop_window()   File "C:\1_python\Photoshop draw circle in untitled-1 with spacebar.py", line 9, in
maximize_photoshop_window
    photoshop_window = pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle("Adobe Photoshop")[0]
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^ 
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1

Wonder what is happening here?

Looks like you try to access an index outside the size of a list ("IndexError: list index out of range"). Please read your error message. The function call returns a list with a length below 1.

getWindowsWithTitle returns a list of all the windows with the given title. According to the error message, in this case, it returned an empty list, which probably means that "Adobe Photoshop" isn't the exact title of the window.

You are correct. In fact I ran a script which lists the running programs and Photoshop is not even listed, although the document (Untitled-1 @ 50% (RGB/8)) is there..Thanks!!
